# Transform data within a Redux reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

seems like I am thinking in the wrong direction.. I have a react app that's using redux. Now I have a reducer that's getting data from a server. For one Component, I need the data to be transformed which I'd like to do within the reducer.

But if I transform the data, it's transformed for all subscribers isn't it?
So is it possible to transform data within a reducer on the fly, but doesn't save the transformed data within the state? (Well this sounds like a dump question..)

Comment: The action would fetch the data and dispatch it to the store, the store as you said is global, but you could store that data under a sub key with some unique ID for that component instance to use

Comment: Why not just do the transformation in the components that wants the transformation? If it's a generic transformation make a function that does the transformation and reuse that.

Comment: Wait.. the action itself put the data into the state and the reducer only reduces the complete state and returns the little snipped that is needed? So the reducers return value isn't stored anywhere but just forwarded to the subscribers?

Comment: The reducers return value sets the state of the store.

Comment: so it's just like the opposite of what @DominicTobias just said?

Comment: He is suggesting that the store is dumber - it keeps all the data you need, and the component itself transforms that data for it's purposes. It probably depends on what the requirements/data looks like.

Comment: Well that drives me nuts. if the reducers return value would be the new state that will be stored, than this should not work:
unction selectTodos(todos, filter) {
  switch (filter) {
  case VisibilityFilters.SHOW_ALL:
    return todos
  case VisibilityFilters.SHOW_COMPLETED:
    return todos.filter(todo => todo.completed)
  case VisibilityFilters.SHOW_ACTIVE:
    return todos.filter(todo => !todo.completed)
  }
}
The filter returns a reduced array which doesn't contain all values, so every subscriber getting the data afterwards would never see the complete data

Comment: @Christian the only way such a thing could work is if you had an original list and a filtered list. If you look at the ComputingDerivedData link in the answer below under "Creating a Memoized Selector" you will see there is a `todos` (all data) and a `visibleTodos` which is computed from `todos` each time the VisibilityFilter is changed

Answer (score 4):

Often components will need special data that can be derived from store state, but which isn't store state. As one comment suggests, you can just write a function that does the transformation, and call it from the component. These functions are sometimes called 'selectors', since they select and transform parts of the state. However, this can cause problems, since the value will be re-computed every time any state changes, and since it's derived data, everything depending on it will be re-rendered.

There is a redux extension library that provides a solution to this problem, by allowing you effectively to declare the precise parts of the state that your selector depends on. This means it will only be recomputed when these parts change, avoiding the re-render every time problem. See:
http://rackt.org/redux/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html
and https://github.com/rackt/reselect

You may choose to completely encapsulate your store state, and have components only ever access the state via selectors. This has the usual encapsulation and related benefits (e.g. insulating your components from some re-factorings to the store state).